# Question should be reopen?

Tags: discussion, support

Today I have been reviewing the [Reopen Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/10565947) queue and reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283637/find-size-of-one-index-and-assign-a-value-of-a-multidimensional-array) which has been marked as a duplicate.

OP edited the post with a new question which is related to their previous issue.

```
My next question is that blah blah blah...
```

Should I reopen this new question or leave it closed?

Can we ask a related new question if it is marked as a duplicate?

Comment: If they have a new question, they should ask a new question surely?

Comment: @TZHX Even though it is related to previous question/answer then also, can not do like that. right?

Comment: Lots of questions are related to other questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't vote to reopen. The question already have an answer that answers the original question (which is duplicate).

If they have a new question, it should be a new question and not an edit.

Comment: Even though it is related to previous question/answer then also, can not do like that. right?

Comment: @ketan No. Otherwise we might end up with endless editing for related questions.